# Механизм function-to-pointer conversions и отличие имени функции func от &func?

Tags: c++

В голове полная каша в этих вопросах, проясните пожалуйста все по полочкам..

Почему это утверждение:

```
void func(){};
static_assert(is_same<void(*)(), decltype(func)>::value);
```

дает ошибку? Почему func тут не распадается до указателя на себя? Если я правильно понимаю, funс будет тем же самым что и &funс, но разница в том, что &funс сразу возвращает указатель на функцию, а funс (нативно) возвращает тип функции (или ссылку?), но автоматически преобразуется к указателю на функцию и становится тем же, что и &funс, верно? А в decltype этого преобразования (function-to-pointer conversions) не происходит, правильно?

В общем, когда мы используем имя функции в качестве выражения, оно распадается до указателя на само себя, но что это означает - что создается отдельная переменная-указатель, которая содержит адрес функции? Но что за адрес она может содержать, если функция это не объект?

А &func возвращает сразу указатель на функцию без каких-либо дополнительных преобразований? И опять-таки, что в этом контексте значит указатель - отдельная переменная в памяти? Или адрес в памяти? Но почему тогда называется указатель?

Comment: Имя функции может неявно преобразовываться в указатель в *подходящем контексте*.

Comment: неявно преобразовывается из какого типа? "В указатель" - значит создается переменная* памяти, содержащая адрес? Адрес чего она содержит. если функция - не объект?

Comment: точно также имя массива не есть указатель, но неявно преобразовывается в указатель. decltype выдает 
реальный тип, а не то, чему можно присвоить

Comment: Преобразуется из типи функции, переменная не создается, создается временный объект - указатель, содержащий адрес функции.

Comment: "Преобразуется из типи функции" - что имеется ввиду из типа функции? Может быть речь идет о том, что ссылка (адрес) преобразуется к указателю (объекту)?

Comment: Скорее всего вы не понимаете, что возвращение результата функций использует дополнительный буфер. И `return что-то` использует временный участок памяти для возврата функции. `Тип Функция(){return Что-то;}` создаёт **новый** объект `Тип{Что-то}` и отдаёт вызывающему коду. Это создание результата и вызывает соответствующие преобразования типов, что надо.

Comment: И еще, объясните мне пожалуйста, почему операция взятия адреса &funс превращает имя функции в указатель, а не в адрес?

Comment: `&func` это указатель типа `void(*)()` и он указывает на "объект" типа `void()`. Непонятно, что вам непонятно...

Comment: AlexGlebe, да, действительно этого не понимаю. А почему создание результата вызывает преобразования типов? Какая связь? И еще, оптимизация компилятора не упраздняет создание нового временного объекта для вызывающего кода? Или упраздняет только вызов  конструкторов?

Comment: Указатель это и есть адрес. А еще задавайте строго по одному вопросу в вопросе.

Comment: Напишите `static_assert(is_same<void(), decltype(func)>::value);`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ссылок на функции в вашем примере нет. Вопреки распространенному заблуждению, [выражения не бывают ссылками](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-1). Ссылки всегда объявляются, например так: `auto &x = func;`.

Здесь появляется разница между типом выражения `x` и типом переменной `x`. Тип переменной - ссылка, но единственное место, где он может всплыть - это в `decltype(x)`. В остальных местах важен только тип как выражения, и он уже не ссылка, а просто функция. Например в `x();` или `bar(x);`.

> когда мы используем имя функции в качестве выражения, оно распадается до указателя на само себя

Не при любом использовании. Например, здесь не распадается:

```
template <typename F>
void bar(F &) {}

bar(func);
```

> распадается до указателя на само себя, но что это означает - что создается отдельная переменная-указатель, которая содержит адрес функции?

Да, но только объект, а не переменная. Переменные всегда объявляются (ссылки - подвид переменных), например `auto &x = func;` или `auto *x = func;` (можно без звездочки - это то же самое).

Все переменные (кроме ссылок) - это объекты, но не все объекты - переменные.

(Хотя, даже с тем, что это объект, можно поспорить - читайте про mandatory copy elision. Поскольку `&func` (или результат распада `func` до указателя) - это prvalue, сам объект появляется не сразу, а когда становится нужен. Например, в `auto *x = func;` объект один - `x`, распад не порождает второй (временный) объект. Но здесь это все не важно, ведь раз это не класс (у которых бывают конструкторы и деструкторы), нельзя никак пронаблюдать, сколько объектов на самом деле создается.)

> Но что за адрес она может содержать, если функция это не объект?

Адрес функции, очевидно. Следствие: адреса бывают не только у объектов, но и у функций тоже. Скорее всего, это адрес первой процессорной инструкции этой функции.

> А &func возвращает сразу указатель на функцию без каких-либо дополнительных преобразований?

Да.

> И опять-таки, что в этом контексте значит указатель - отдельная переменная в памяти? Или адрес в памяти? Но почему тогда называется указатель?

Не переменная, потому что не объявлен. Не объект, потому что prvalue. Просто prvalue-указатель на функцию.

> Или адрес в памяти?

Адрес - это значение указателя, так же как число - это значение (например) `int`а.

Поэтому создается указатель, значением которого является адрес функции.

Comment: _"Не при любом использовании. Например:"_ - это пример какого случая? Когда там указатель или когда не указатель? И почему так?

Comment: @Qwertiy Раз автор думает, что всегда распадается, то, конечно, это пример обратной ситуации. Но дописал. *"И почему так?"* Как объяснить, почему? Потому что язык так сделан.

Comment: Спасибо! Очень доходчиво. А еще можете подсказать, чем является имя функции ДО неявного преобразования к указателю (в подходящем контексте)? Типом функции? А что такое тип функции в машинном представлении? Какая-то константа времени компиляции, адрес, или что?

Comment: @Давид *"Типом функции?"* Угу. *"что такое тип функции в машинном представлении?"* `sizeof` на функции не работает, поэтому с точки зрения языка это просто какая-то непонятная штука, которую можно вызвать или преобразовать в указатель/ссылку. Адрес, который при этом получается - это адрес первой инструкции функции в памяти.

Comment: Вы пишете «Не объект, потому что prvalue. Просто prvalue-указатель на функцию.» Я может быть неправильно понимаю что такое указатель, объясните пожалуйста, как указатель может быть prvalur, если указатель - это идентифицируемый объект в памяти, который может быть разыменован?

Comment: @Давид, одно и то же слово может иметь разные значения в зависимости от контекста. Словом «указатель» обозначают не только объект в памяти но и _тип_. Фраза «prvalue-указатель на функцию» обозначает, что выражение `&func` — это `prvalue` имеющее тип _указатель на функцию_, т.е. выражение  `&func` — это `prvalue` имеющее тип `void(*)()`.

Comment: @Давид Получается, что указатель - не всегда объект. Но это уже дебри и занудство, часто prvalue называют (неправильно) временными объектами, и не заморачиваются.